# How to store usernames from php session to socket.io library in nodejs and socket connection disconnects on page refresh.Why?

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am making a chat application for my web job portal.I used to save user's name from php session to nodejs socket io library..I am confused..it is ok to store 10k users in socket object.if yes then how to maintain that users list? Another problem is when user navigates from one page to another..socket disconnect and again connect..Does it effect my application performance or nodejs server perform?

Please guide me through tutorials or blog..I have not find relevant docs yet about socket connection management ..Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The client automatically closes any socket when the user navigates to a different page. This is a normal behaviour ("it's a feature").

Comment: How to fix that problem ..Is it any way to handle socket connection until user closes the browser and then disconnect only?

Answer (score 3):

You can store your data into `socket`.
For example,

**On Server side, use like this,**

```
    var socketIo = require('/socket.io').listen(8080);
    var usernames=[];    

    socketIo.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {    
        socket.on('storeUserData', function (data) {  
           var userInfo = new Object();
           userInfo.userName = data.userName;
           userInfo.SocketId = socket.id;
            usernames.push(userInfo);
        });    

        socket.on('disconnect', function (data) {
         var len = usernames.length;

            for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                var user = usernames[i];

                if(user.socketId == socket.id){
                    usernames.splice(i,1);
                    break;
                }
            }    
        });
    });
```

and on client side, you need to add this

```
<script>
    var userName = <?php echo $_SESSION['userName'] ?>;        
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost', {port: 8080});    
    socket.on('connect', function (data) {
        socket.emit('storeUserData', { 'userName' : userName });
    });
</script>
```

> Socket connection disconnects on page refresh.Why?

It is default behaviour of `socket.io`.

Comment: Is it ok to store 10k username in javascript array concurrently for my portal? Some time it gives Maximum stack over-exceeded error?

Comment: @GouravRathore; You can use database in back-end if you have huge storage requirements. Even you can use `Redis`.

Comment: Thanks for your act of kindness...can you give me any redis example to store user data or any kind of tutorial or blog to read out and understand..I am new to use redis...Thanks in advance!!